# Strip php tags from user-created code

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage where users can edit, create, store, access and debug their HTML codes online. For security purpuses I am already using a sandboxed iframe to display the user content, but there is one more thing I've though about - what if the user created code contains a php tag (my serverside language is php) that, for instance, makes an SQL query and reads/deletes all of my databases or does anything else that is harmful?

Is it possible? If yes - how can I defend myself against this type of attack? I do know that php has an option to strip all tags with certain tagnames, so I can strip all the php tags, but then again - can the users still not use other hacks, such as document.write() the php tag or something like that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's  rule  #1 : Always verify user input. You will have to verify code sent for `<?` and `<?php` tag to prevent any suspicious code.

Comment: I agree but what if they do something like document.write("<?php ...>")?

Answer (score 0):

The php tag (`<?php ?>`) isn't a HTML tag (`<html><strong>` and so on). So that would not really be possible.

On the other hand they could insert javascript (xss). You can escape the output, or filter the input.

For filtering the input see: http://php.net/strip_tags

You can pass the tags you want to keep as a parameter like this:

```
strip_tags($input, '<br>');
```